# '__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument' error in Dash

Tags: python, html, css, jupyter-notebook

I am working on Jupyter Notebook and i am trying to use an external css sheet for a Dash app
but i get the error above, Forgive me if it’s something very obvious as i am very new to this.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash


external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(input_value)

app

Out: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'external_stylesheets'
```

Comment: What is your `dash` version?

Comment: I have dash 1.10.0